# Arithmetic mean b/w two terms of an A.P

Tags: sequences-and-series, arithmetic-progressions

I came across the following question in my textbook today:

> If A.M b/w $p$th and $q$th terms of an A.P be equal to the A.M b/w the $r$th and $s$th terms of the A.P, then prove that $p+q=r+s$

My first instinct was to assume that there is but a *single* A.M b/w $p$ and $q$, and similarly for $r$ and $s$. Proceeding in this manner, we get

$(p+q)/2$=$(r+s)/2$ which gives us the required condition almost **too** easily.

I dunno how to proceed in any other way because I'm unable to interpret the question in any other way correctly; if there are actually more than one A.Ms b/w $p$ & $q$ and $r$ & $s$, then, we still don't know if they have the same number of A.Ms b/w them or different.

Supposing that there really *are* more than one A.Ms b/w them, what does the statement "A.M b/w $p$th and $q$th terms of an A.P be equal to the A.M b/w $r$th and $s$th terms of the A.P" even mean? Do they mean to say that the arithmetic mean of the arithmetic means are equal?

Please help! MUCH thanks in advance :) Regards.

Comment: I can guess that "A.P." is arithmetic progression and "A.M." is arithmetic mean, but "b/w" seems like a strange and baffling abbreviation for "of".

Comment: Sorry. b/w is "between"; it's actually a quite popular abbreviation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pth term of an arithmetic progression is given by the formula $a + (p-1)d$, where $a$ is the first term and $d$ is the difference.

So, we can write down the other terms:

$q$th term $= a + (q-1)d$

$r$th term $= a + (r-1)d$

$s$th term $= a + (s-1)d$

If $d=0$ the problem is obvious, and I'll leave it to you. We will assume that $d \neq 0$.

Now, the arithmetic mean of two quantities is just their average. So  the arithmetic mean of the $p$th and the $q$th term is $\frac{a + (p-1)d+a + (q-1)d}{2}$. Similarly,  the arithmetic mean of the $r$th and the $s$th term is $\frac{a + (r-1)d+a + (s-1)d}{2}$.

Now the question says that these are equal hence, we see that:
$$
\frac{a + (r-1)d+a + (s-1)d}{2} = \frac{a + (p-1)d+a + (q-1)d}{2}
$$

Subtract the quantity $\frac{2a-2d}{2}$ from both sides, and you will get:

$$
\frac{rd+sd}{2} = \frac{pd+ qd}{2}
$$
Finally, divide by $d/2$ on both sides:
$$
r+s=p+q
$$
This should do it.

Comment: Oh God, I feel **mortified**; I understood the question completely wrongly! I thought that $p$ and $q$ were the terms themselves! *Sheesh*. I'm almost tempted to delete the question but I will accept your answer and leave it up, for your(and other answerers') effort. Thanks :-)

Comment: @KaumudiHarikumar That's happened to me just about as often as I blink. It's ok,you will get  over it. Thank you for your appreciation.

Answer (score 0):

it is given $$a_p=a_1+(p-1)d,a_q=a_1+(q-1)d$$ and $$a_r=a_1+(r-1)d,a_s=(s-1)d$$ thus we obtain
$$\frac{a_p+a_q}{2}=\frac{2a_1+(p-1)d+(q-1)d}{2}$$ and
$$\frac{a_r+a_s}{2}=\frac{2a_1+(r-1)d+(s-1)d}{2}$$ and we get
$$pd+qd=rd+sd$$ if $d\ne 0$ we get
$$p+q=r+s$$ what was to show

Comment: why the $$-1$$? i don't understand!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Doctor, neither do I. I've restored it.

Comment: why was my solution downvoted?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner What do you mean?

Comment: Like I have mentioned in the comments of the answer given by @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрr, I feel **mortified**, because I understood the question **completely** wrongly! Sheesh, I could easily have solved this, had I understood it correctly. Thanks for your explanation :-)